# Android GLSurfaceView over MediaPlayer-SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, surfaceview, android-mediaplayer, glsurfaceview

I have a `MediaPlayer` using a `SurfaceView` to display the video. And now I want to add a `GlSurfaceView` over the `MediaPlayerto` to render a cube over the video. I am using a relative layout. And I can do both work separated however, I am not able to put the `GlSurfaceView` over the `SurfaceView`. It simply does not render the OpenGL code that I use for the cube.
Can some one help?

```
   _cube = new CubeGLView(this);
   _cube.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
   _cube.setId(10002);
   _cube.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
   _cube.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
   //_cube.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

   _render = new GlRenderer(_cube.getContext());
   _cube.setRenderer(_render);
   _cube.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

   mPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);
   _cube.setLayoutParams(lp);

   layout.addView(_cube);
   layout.addView(mPreview);

   setContentView(layout, rlp);
```

Answer (score 2):

resolve it:
mPreview = new SurfaceView(this);
        mPreview.setId(10001);

```
    mPreview.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPreview.setClickable(true);

    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();


    _cube = new CubeGLView(this);
    _cube.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

    _cube.setId(10002);
    _cube.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    _cube.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);


    _render = new GlRenderer(_cube.getContext());
    _cube.setRenderer(_render);



    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    mPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(100,10, 0,0);
    _cube.setLayoutParams(params);

    DataManager datamanager = DataManager.getInstance();

    if (!datamanager.isHasalreadyview()){
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate icicle == null");
        layout.addView(_cube);
        layout.addView(mPreview);
        datamanager.setHasalreadyview(true);
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate icicle != null");
        layout.addView(mPreview);
        layout.addView(_cube);
    }


    setContentView(layout, rlp);
```